# On iOS missing `session cookies` used React Native WebView

Tags: ios, react-native, cookies, webview

**Bug description:**
My WebView should display a web page that has a cookie authentication. The page expects a session-id cookie acquired on login. To authenticate I send the login request to the website using fetch().

When the login is successful I can see that proper cookies are received. On success, I'm starting the WebView.

**It works perfectly on Android but not on iOS.**

I tested it on iOS 9 and iOS 11 simulators, and on an iOS 11 device.

To sum up the question: **Why cookies I've got with fetch aren't passed to WebView on iOS only.**

```
<WebView 
    source = {{
        uri: url,
    }}
    onLoadEnd={() => {
        CookieManager.getAll().then((cookies) => {
            console.log('CookieManager.getAll =>', cookies);
        });
    }}
/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khoNO.png)

**Environment:**

- OS:  IOS
- OS version:   14.4.2
- react-native version:   0.64
- react-native-webview version:  ^11.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `getAllCookies` to get cookies from wkwebview, like [this](https://qastack.cn/programming/33156567/getting-all-cookies-from-wkwebview).

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
  [webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore
      getAllCookies:^(NSArray<NSHTTPCookie *> *_Nonnull cookies) {
        NSURLRequest *request =
            [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.URL]; //your URL
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session
            dataTaskWithRequest:request
              completionHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSURLResponse *response,
                                  NSError *error) {
                //Do Something
              }];
        [task resume];
        [session.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage storeCookies:cookies forTask:task];
      }];
}
```